# MySQL: SELECT returns no results, but INSERT throws 'Duplicate Entry' error

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to work with a table of product descriptions, and I've got a head scratcher...
I've got a method (php) which looks for the ID key of a record.
If a match to the search criteria ***does not exist***, it attempts to create the row and return that ID.

Right now, the SELECT is returning Zero rows, but an INSERT with the same values is throwing a dupe error.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`m3sandbox_product_description`)
WHERE `product_id` =  '403466'
AND `company_id` =  '5'
AND `value` =  'TERMINAL, FEMALE DISCONNECT, 6.3MM, RED; Connector Type:Female Disconnect; Insulator Color:Red; Termination Method:Crimp; Stud/Tab Size:6.35mm x 0.81mm; Wire Size (AWG):22AWG to 16AWG; Contact Material:Copper; Contact Plating:Tin ;RoHS Compliant: Yes'
LIMIT 1
```

.

```
INSERT INTO `m3sandbox_product_description`  (`product_id`, `company_id`, `value`, `datetime_created`)
VALUES  ('403466', '5', 'TERMINAL, FEMALE DISCONNECT, 6.3MM, RED; Connector Type:Female Disconnect; Insulator Color:Red; Termination Method:Crimp; Stud/Tab Size:6.35mm x 0.81mm; Wire Size (AWG):22AWG to 16AWG; Contact Material:Copper; Contact Plating:Tin ;RoHS Compliant: Yes', '2012-10-16T15:39:44+00:00')
```

As it turns out, the other developer in our Co using a completely different code base (but similar approach) against this same DB, and he's facing the exact same peculiar hurdle.

**Is** there something special we should be doing to query with description values like to ensure that our SELECT's behave as intended **?**

Comment: The PK, which is auto incremented, is `id` (not utilized in these queries) ... this table has a unique index over the `value`, `product_id`, and `company_id` fields.

Comment: well, could it be that your auto_increment sequence was reset? That happened to me a few times. What DBMS do you use? How many records do you have? Did you insert any records with a fixed Id?

Comment: @jeroen-vuurens Yes and Maybe :) .. The other dev'r was using the live table and I'm unsure about all the specifics around his experience ... in my case though, I'm using a "sandbox" copy of the live table and I _**did**_ try inserting a row before I remembered to set the ID to auto_increment ... after that, the auto_increment _**was**_ reset (the next auto_increment value _currently_ looks right) ... I'm glad this is a little familiar to someone. Please share more on your similar past experiences/solutions ... BTW, the table currently has almost 540-thousand rows.

Comment: Ah so there you go. If you inserted rows before switching to auto increment, it's quite likely that the sequence the DBMS uses is still set to a value lower than the current max(id). Depending on the DBMS you use you may be able to set the last auto_increment value. If you can set that to max(id) you should be fine from thereon.

Comment: @JeroenVuurens The next value for auto_increment has been reset and confirmed .. *BUT* I'm pretty sure the problem lays in the SELECT rather than the INSERT because no match is found ... wait .. that gives me an idea ... let me look into something and I'll post back soon

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate entry is triggered by a duplicate primary key only, regardless of the other values used. If product_id is the primary key(?), then maybe a record exists for product_id = 403466 with different other values?

Comment: Thanks .. see my new comment on the OP

Answer (score 1):

*I found it!!!!*

**TERMINAL STRING LENGTH**

The long text value of the search/insert statements exceed the column size, so, when searching  for that long string ***is no*** exact match, but when inserting, the end of the string is truncated and the new truncated string ***does*** have an exact match.

I hope this can help someone in the future :)

Comment: I'll try to come back after the SO imposed 2-day waiting period and mark this as the answer :)